# Not getting all records from SELECT statement in PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I want to get some records using SELECT Statement from this table:
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0pVO.png)

My SELECT Statement:

```
$getDates="SELECT daily_rate_date, daily_rate_price FROM daily_rates WHERE daily_rate_date >= '".$checkOut."'  AND   daily_rate_date < '".$departureDate."' AND   daily_rate_reservation=$reservationId;";
```

When I echo this query It shows this:

```
SELECT daily_rate_date, daily_rate_price FROM daily_rates WHERE daily_rate_date >= '2021-03-03' AND daily_rate_date < '2021-03-08' AND daily_rate_reservation=65;
```

The problem is that when I use this query in Xammp it does not return all the results that i need as you can see in the next picture:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyA7o.png)

Comment: Two of those five rows don't satisfy the date criteria.

Comment: What results are missing?

Comment: And, since you're a newcomer, I would recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

Comment: The last 2 rows are a different month than your date range. Look closely.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your SQL query is doing exactly what you want it to do; looking for daily_rate_dates between 2021-03-03 and 2021-03-08. If you want daily_rate_id then your SQL query should look like this:

```
$getDates="SELECT daily_rate_id, daily_rate_date, daily_rate_price 
FROM daily_rates 
WHERE daily_rate_date BETWEEN {$checkOut} AND {$departureDate} 
AND daily_rate_reservation={$reservationId};";
```

If you're looking for those rows in a different month, well your parameters are off. Additionally, you should use prepared statements instead of this direct querying.